# How to load a library from a user supplied directory?

Tags: java, android, static, libraries

My Android application loads a self developed library by calling `System.loadLibrary ("midi");`. It loads `libmidi.so` from `/system/lib` or `/vendor/lib`. As these are system library directories I am not able to put the library in `/vendor/lib`. I rooted my Nexus to test the application but this is obviously not the way how to deploy an application. So instead of using `loadLibrary` I should use `load` and giving it the path to e.g. `dataDir ()` like:

```
public class MidiDriver implements Runnable
{
    // declarations of variables and methods and at the end:
    static
    {
//       System.loadLibrary ("midi");
       String s = Context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;       
       System.load (s + "midi");
    }
}
```

I get the error " cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationInfo ()". I do not know how I should solve this error. Any ideas someone?

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference to a `Context` which you can't have within a static initializer block because it does not accept parameters. Your best bet is to load the library within your own `Application` subclass in `onCreate`.

```
package com.example;
// imports
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String path = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir, "midi").getPath();
        System.loadLibrary(path);
    }
}
```

Then add the name of your application to the manifest. e.g.

```
...
<application
    android:name="com.example.CustomApplication"
    ...
```

---

If that doesn't work, you'll need some construct that allows passing in a reference while ensuring that the library is only loaded once. E.g.

```
public class Init {
    private static final AtomicBoolean STATE = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (STATE.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            String path = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir, "midi").getPath();
            System.loadLibrary(path);
        }
    }
}
```

would run only the first time you call `Init.init(somecontext)`, but I doubt that you can use it from within your `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborated answer!Trouble is that I have no control over the application as that is generated by delphi. It would greatly help if I could access the app home directory by the load command.

Comment: You can't :) There are some ways like storing the context in a `static` variable, then accessing it from there but that requires very careful examintion and is more or less a hack.

Comment: Mmm, seems I am stuck. Can I transmit a parameter to this static construct?